# Convergence of a series with factorials, parameters and ratio test

Tags: calculus

**Question:** 
check when does $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty {\sqrt[m] {n!} \over  \sqrt[k] {(2n)!}}$ converge/diverge?

**What I did:**

Using the ratio test:
$$ {\sqrt[m] {(n+1)!} \over {\sqrt[k] {(2n+2)!} }} \cdot {\sqrt[k] {(2n)!} \over \sqrt[m] {n!}}= {{(n+1)^{\frac 1m}} \over { {((2n+2)(2n+1))}^{\frac 1k}}}=  {{(n+1)^{\frac 1m}} \over { {2^{\frac 1k}(n+1)^{\frac 1k}(2n+1)}^{\frac 1k}}}=$$

- We check in which cases $\frac 1m$ is a leading power (in that case the $\lim_{n \to \infty} {{(n+1)^{\frac 1m}} \over { {((2n+2)(2n+1))}^{\frac 1k}}}= \infty $) and when is $\frac 1k$ is a leading power and then the limit is 0.
- The thing that I'm stuck with is how to see which k's and m's are causing this limit to go to 0 (should i just divide the cases to km)?
  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence looks like $\dfrac{n^\frac{1}{m}}{n^\frac{2}{k}}$.

Comment: shuuld I get to that using the squeeze theorem?